# Aliasing of multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing

It is well known that a 2D array is an array of arrays, and that it is required by standard to be *a contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects* (6.2.5 Types §20) - object being a 1D array here.

It is also well known that for all common implementations the following equality is true for `T arr2d[X][Y]` where T is a type and X and Y integral constants:

```
(char *) &arr2d[i][j] == (char *) &arr2d[0][0] + i * Y * sizeof(T) + j * sizeof(T)
```

The above let think that it could be allowed to alias a 2D array and an 1D array of same size, or even another 2D array of same total size:

For example the following program compiles and runs with no warnings, and gives expected output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, j, k=0;
    int arr2d[3][4];   // array of 3 array of 4 ints
    int *arr1 = &arr2d[0][0];  // pointer to first element of an array of 12 ints (1)
    int (*arrx)[3] = (int(*)[3]) arr1; //pointer to first row of an array of arrays of 3 ints
                                       //(2)

    for (i=0; i<12; i++) arr1[i] = k++; // (3)

    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<4; j++) {
            printf("%3d", arr2d[i][j]);
        }
        putc('\n', stdout);
    }
    for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<3; j++) {
            printf("%3d", arrx[i][j]); 
        }
        putc('\n', stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But:

- line (1) and (3) *alias* a 2D array 3x4 to a 1D array 12
- line (2) *alias* a 2D array 3x4 to a 2D array 4x3 (via a pointer to int)

My questions are:

- are (1) and (3) valid according to the C standard?
- if yes, is (2) valid?

Comment: I know that only one single question should be asked, but here the second one is just a complement to the first one.

Comment: I think the key here is that both arrays are aggregates that both contain the item `int` among its members "including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate". C11 6.5/7.

Comment: @Lunin My doubts come from 6.7.5.2 Array declarators *For two array types to be compatible, ... both size
specifiers shall have **the same constant value**.*

Comment: To nitpick, but the equality you mentioned misses a cast to (unsigned) char, and then a cast back to `T*`

Comment: @SergeBallesta The arrays here are not compatible types, but they can still alias each other, because of the various exceptions to the mentioned strict aliasing rule.

Comment: @StoryTeller: The point was not there, but it is now more correct...

Comment: @Lundin Type `int(*)[3]` can't alias an array of type `int[3][4]`. Two separate accesses happen, a[0] and then a[0][0]. The latter one is compatible because the effective type is int and access is done through int, but the former one is not, because the effective type is `int[4]` and the access is done through `char[3]`

Comment: @SergeBallesta The claim: *pointer to first element of an array of 12 ints (1)* Where/how does the array of type int[12] appear there?

Comment: @2501: In the code, at line noted (3), I use the pointer to first element in a loop of size 12. AFAIK, pointer arithmetics is only valid inside an array, so I assume I can only to that if `arr1` points to an integer array of size (at least) 12. Per the declaration, `arr[0][0]` is element of a row, that is an array of size 4, so `arr1[i]` is guaranteed valid for i in [0,3].

Comment: @SergeBallesta That doesn't seem relevant. Accesses don't determine a type of an object in this case. The objects at the memory location indicated by the indentifier arr2d are: `int[3][4]`, three `int[4]`s, and twelve individual `int`s. There is no type char[12] at that location.

Comment: This follows that the access here  `for (i=0; i<12; i++) arr1[i] = k++; // (3)`, when value of i is 4, is out of bounds of the inner array, as the pointer is one past the last element. It happens that there is some object there (an int), but strictly reading the standard, it is still out of bounds and ub.

Comment: @2501: That's exactly the reason why I have asked this question here: I agree with your arguments, but the aliasing (1) (3) of `arr1` is very common and was the only way to process array of dynamic sizes before VLA.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I wouldn't bet on arguments from popularity. What is wrong with using two loops?

Comment: @2501:Nothing is wrong. But I have already encountered use cases where it did make sense to see a 2D array as a 1D one, for example to pass it to a function in legacy code that uses explicit 2D pointer arithmetic on a 1D array. And anyway, I willingly put the language-lawyer tag, because I hope solid advices

Comment: @SergeBallesta So you're worried about legacy code? In that case use appropriate compiler flags and be done with it. i don't see any reason to do this in modern C code.

Comment: @2501: If the Standard had specified that use of the `+` or `[]` operators directly on something of array type could processed in a fashion other than by converting the array's address into a pointer-to-element type, adding the appropriate index, and (for `[]`) applying unary `*` to the result, then it would make sense to say that use of such operators on array types would only yield defined behavior in a fraction of the cases where a manual cast to the pointer-to-element type followed by an indexing operation would do so.  The Standard doesn't say any such thing, however.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Even if the strict aliasing rules allows to access an object of one type from an object containing it, there are two elements in standards to say that aliasing a 2D array to a 1D array of same size is not allowed:

Compatible type

> 6.2.7 Compatible type and composite type
>
> 1 Two types have compatible type if their types are the same.
> ...
>   3 A composite type can be constructed from two types that are compatible; it is a type that
>   is compatible with both of the two types and satisfies the following conditions:
>
> - **If one type is an array of known constant size, the composite type is an array of that
>     size**; otherwise, if one type is a variable length array, the composite type is that type.
>   ...
>
> **These rules apply recursively to the types from which the two types are derived**.

Conformance:

> 4 Conformance
>
> ...
>
> 2. ... Undefined behavior is otherwise indicated in this International
>      Standard by the words ‘‘undefined behavior’’ or by the **omission of any explicit definition
>      of behavior**. There is no difference in emphasis among these three; they all describe
>      **‘‘behavior that is undefined’’**.
> 3. A program that is correct in all other aspects, operating on correct data, containing
>      unspecified behavior shall be a correct program and act in accordance with 5.1.2.3.
>      ...
> 4. A strictly conforming program shall use only those features of the language and library
>      specified in this International Standard.2) **It shall not produce output dependent on any
>      unspecified, undefined, or implementation-defined behavior**, and shall not exceed any
>      minimum implementation limit.

My understanding is that aliasing of 2D array with a 1D array is *unspecified* by the standard and as such leads to undefined behaviour. A program using it is still *a correct program* that shall be successfuly compiled, but its output is unspecified

A stricly conforming program should not alias a 2D array to an 1D array.

That being said, common implementation allows it and process it *as expected* (which is allowed per undefined behaviour...) in order to not break legacy code that heavily depends on it.

Comment: This answer uses the comments to the question, many thanks to Lundin, 2501 and supercat for their help.

Comment: In cases where two pointer values of the same type would be required to identify the same address, and where the behavior of accessing one would be defined, the authors of the C89 didn't bother to list cases where accesses to the other would be likewise defined since that would have been implied by pointer equivalence.  Unfortunately, later versions of the Standard changed the meaning of pointers such that the aforementioned equivalence doesn't hold, but didn't revisit cases whose behavior had been defined by such equivalence.  What's ironic is that the Standard imposes many restrictions...

Comment: ...on memory layout which would serve a useful purpose if code could exploit the addressing relations they implied thereby (e.g. the requirement that arrays have no padding was useful mainly because it implied that 2d arrays could be read out as a single sequence of elements).  If code can't exploit such guaranteed aspects of the layout, there's little benefit to mandating them,.

Comment: "My understanding is that aliasing of 2D array with a 1D array is unspecified by the standard and as such leads to undefined behaviour"   -- you have not established that it is unspecified  ; and also it is not correct to claim that any program with unspecified behaviour also has undefined behaviour .  Nor is it clear why you quoted 6.2.7 since you do not draw any conclusions from the text you quoted

Comment: @M.M. As I said, this answer was mainly compiled from comments. I would be glad that you can prove me that it is wrong.