# pointers and 2-D arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I know how can I use pointers in C with the 1-D array. like the following:
but what if we have 2-D arrays? how can I address them by pointers? 
Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int dar[4] = {1,2,3,4};

  int *sar = NULL;
  sar = dar;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    printf("%d ", *(sar + i));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's usually best to store your 2D array as a 1D array.

Comment: Use`int *` instead of `int **` for 2-D arrays.

Comment: `*(sar + (row * width) + column)`

Comment: @Qubit - thats actually what the compiler does for you

Comment: [You might want to take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Comment: @pm100 Yes, it does, but only in the case of static allocation, which comes with some limitations regarding size.

Answer (score 1):

This may also help.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{   
    int dar[2][3] = {1,2,3,
                    4,5,6}; 
    int index=0;
    for (int line = 0; line < 2; line++) 
    {
        for (int col=0; col<3;col++)
        {               
            printf("%d ", *(dar[0]+index));
            index=index+1;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }   
    return (0);
```

}

Comment: It works, but is bad. You are aliasing a 2-D array 2x3 to a 1-D array of size 6. According to this [other question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42951932/3545273), this is unspecified by the standard and hence formal Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta Aliasing a 2-D array to a 1-D array was exactly my purpose.  I studied the link that you provided but I did not come to the same understanding as you. I am not an expert in C but I cannot agree with you. The main reason is that a static array is in a contiguously allocated block of memory. So to access its elements is a matter of simple  pointer arithmetic. Please excuse my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Qubit
I solved the problem. I post the answer for future reference.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int dar[2][3] = {{1,2,3},
                   {4,5,6}};

  int *sar = NULL;
  int *bar = NULL;
  sar = dar[0];
  bar = dar[1];

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    printf("%d ", *(sar+i));
   }
  printf("\n");
  for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    printf("%d ",*(bar+j));
   }

   printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: That really isn't what I had in mind. This might work in this case, because it is small, but will scale miserably. I strongly suggest you read up on how arrays are stored.

Comment: thanks @Qubit sure, now I will head up to find some good articles.  :)

Comment: I have posted an improved version of your code below. Feel free to re-use it in your own answer if you like, and accept it (your one). If you ping me in a comment after doing that, I will probably upvote yours and delete mine.

Answer (score 0):

A 2-D array is... a 1-D array of 1-D arrays, and you can use the common pointer arithmetics on both.

That means that you can simply do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int dar[2][3] = {{1,2,3},
                   {4,5,6}};


  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    int *bar = *(dar + i);           // pointer to the row
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      printf("%d ",*(bar+j));        // access the values
     }
     printf("\n");
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

It works, because in `dar + i`,  `dar` decays to a pointer to its first row, so `*(dar + 1)` (which is *by definition `dar[i]`) represents the i-th row and in turn decays to a pointer to the first element of that row.

---

Disclaimer: this is just an addition to JJcopl's answer, but too rich to fit in a comment...