# Convert Pointer to Pointer to a multi-dimensional array

Tags: c++, pointers

Is it possible to convert a one dimensional `const int *const p` pointer of dimension  A*B*C to a pointer to a multi-dimensional array of size `[A][B][C]`?

Comment: You know `A`, `B` and `C` ; you know that `p` is of size `A*B*C` : Yes you can and you have everything you need to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do this.  The key is using a typedef to setup your pointer to the array of pointers so that you don't get too confused.

```
typedef int (*pint3)[A][B];
```

In this line, we set up a type that points to a two-dimensional array of pointers to int.  The 2D array has dimensions equal to two of the dimensions that you originally were considering.

As mentioned in the comments, this method violates aliasing.  This type of pointer reassignment is error-prone and should probably be avoided.

```c++
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int A = 2;
    int B = 2;
    int C = 3;

    int array[]{1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,2, 3,3,3,3};



    const int *const p = array;

    typedef int (*pint3)[A][B];

    auto threeDArray = (pint3) p;

    std::cout << "Printing 3D array:  " << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < C; i++ ) {
        for(int j = 0; j < B; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < A; k++) {
                std::cout << threeDArray[i][j][k];
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Printing array:  
11
11

22
22

33
33


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Doesn't this violate aliasing?

Comment: @AndyG: Yes.  I believe you are correct.  I probably should have mentioned in the intro to the answer that this is a c-style, dangerous method of coding, and not a c++ style.  This method is dangerous for multiple reasons--particularly that you have only manually imposed control over the indices of the array.  I was answering the OP's question, but probably should have included a warning that there are better ways to do this.

Answer (score 2):

#### Usually, it's not possible.

In the first case (an `int[A][B][C]` multi-dimensional array), all of your data is laid out contiguously in memory, and `p[10][20][30]` simply means `*(p + B * C * 10 + B * 20 + 30)`. But the pointer is targeted at an array of pointers; and each of those points to another array of pointers; and only those second arrays point to the data. The data and the second-level pointer-arrays may not be consecutive. So you can certainly not take the address of the first element of data and use an offset to get to what you're looking for.

The exception is the case where someone *does* take care to place all of the data contiguously, with the pointer arrays pointing into it at appropriate positions. In that case you can take `&( *(*(*multidim_ptr)))`, i.e. `&( *(*multidim_ptr))`, as your one-dimension pointer which can be used like `p`.

Comment: And even in that case, you could fall in the 1D-2D arrays aliasing question. I once [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42951932/3545273) it (for C language), and many comments said that it was not explicitely allowed, and because of it invoked undefined behaviour...